# How to determine the equivalents of OH- in a titration curve

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, titration

How does one go about determining the equivalents of $\ce{OH-}$ needed for the titration of a weak acid. For example here is the titration curve for Aspartate:

[image: The titration curve for Aspartate]

Why is the equivalents for $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} = 0.5$? Why not $0.75$ or $0.80$? How was the answer 0.5 derived. How were the equivalents for $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2} = 1.5$? derived? I understand the $\mathrm{pI}$ is 1 because there's a balance of charges but why the 0.5, 1.5, and 2.5

Comment: It is trivial, as by definition of Ka and the derived pKa,  pKa is pH where the ratio of respective concentrations ( exactly rather activities ) is 1:1, therefore the half of the equivalence.

Comment: The answer can also be:  *Because log(1)=0*

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you are titrating a weak acid $\ce{H3A}$ with a strong base.
$$\ce{H3A + OH- -> H2A- + H2O}$$
$$\ce{H2A- + OH- -> HA^{2-} + H2O}$$
$$\ce{HA^{2-} + OH- -> A^{3-} + H2O}$$
When *all* $\ce{H3A}$  reacts with $\ce{OH-}$ to form $\ce{H2A-}$, the first equivalence point is reached.

Before the first equivalence point is reached, the $\ce{H3A}$ and $\ce{H2A-}$ buffer exists, whose pH is given by the [Henderson-Hasselbalch equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henderson%E2%80%93Hasselbalch_equation).
$$\mathrm{ pH = pK_{a1} + log\frac{\ce[H_2A^-]}{\ce{[H3A]}}}$$
When $\mathrm{pH = pK_{a1}}$, $\ce{[H2A-]}$=$\ce{[H3A]}$ which means the first half-equivalence point is reached, which requires $\pu{0.5 equivalents}$ of $\ce{OH-}$.